# 2 million queries against a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to run 2 million queries against a three columns table t (s,p,o) which size is 10 billions rows. The data type of each column is string.

Only two types of queries:

- `select s p o from t where s = param`
- `select s p o from t where o = param`

If I store the table in a Postgresql database takes 6 hours using a Java ThreadPoolExecutor.

Do you think Spark can speed up the queries processing even more?
What would be the best strategy? These are my ideas:

- Load the table into a `dataframe` and launch the queries against the dataframe.
- Load the table into a `parquet` database and launch the queries against this database.
- Use Spark 2.4 to launch queries against the Postgresql database instead of querying directly.
- Use Spark 3.0 to launch queries against the database loaded into [PG-Strom,](https://heterodb.github.io/pg-strom/) an extension module of PostgreSQL with GPU support.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Spark on top of the existing MySQL or PostgresSQL server(s) (without the need to export or even stream data to Spark or Hadoop) can increase query performance more than ten times. Using multiple MySQL servers (replication or Percona XtraDB Cluster) gives us an additional performance increase for some queries. You can also use the Spark cache function to cache the whole MySQL query results table.
The idea is simple: Spark can read MySQL or PostgresSQL data via JDBC and can also execute SQL queries, so we can connect it directly to DB's and run the queries. Why is this faster? For long-running (i.e., reporting or BI) queries, it can be much faster as Spark is a massively parallel system. For example, MySQL can only use one CPU core per query, whereas Spark can use all cores on all cluster nodes.

But I recommend you use No-SQL(HBase, Cassandra,...) or New-SQL solutions for your analyses because they have better performance when the scale of your data increase.

Answer (score 0):

**Static Data? Spark; Otherwise tune Postgres**

If the 10 billion rows are static or rarely updated, your best bet is going to be using Spark **with appropriate partitions**. The magic happens with parallelization, so the more cores you have, the better. You want to aim for partitions that are about half a gig in size each.

Determine the size of the data by running `SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('tablename'));` Divide the result by the number of cores available to Spark until you get between 1/8 and 3/4 gig.

Save as **parquet** if you really have static data or if you want to recover from a failure quickly.

If the source data are updated frequently, you're going to want to add indices in Postgres. It could be as straightforward as adding an index on each column. Partitioning in Postgres would also help.

Stick to Postgres. Newer databases are not appropriate for structured data such as yours. There are parallelization options. Aurora, if you're on AWS.

PG-Strom is not going to work for you here. You have simple data with few columns. Getting them into and out of a GPU is going to slow you down too much.